# Wrong output from OpenSSL's BN_bn2dec?

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to use the BIGNUM facility in OpenSSL. I've written the following test program:

```
BIGNUM someSSLInt;

BN_init(&someSSLInt);

BN_set_word(&someSSLInt, 10);

for (unsigned i=0; i<100000; i++) {
    BN_mul_word(&someSSLInt, 100)
}

char *sslstr=BN_bn2dec(&someSSLInt);
printf("%s",sslstr);
```

Unfortunately, I get a 1 with "only" about 3000 zero's, while I would expect a 1 with 200001 zero's. If I compare the same code with other libraries (e.g. GMP or Tommath) I do get the expected output. Am I using OpenSSL in the wrong way?

I'm using version 1.0.2g on macOS.

Comment: I think you need to call [`BN_new`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/bn.html): *"[BN's] uses dynamic memory allocation for storing its data structures..."*. So maybe something like `BIGNUM* someSSLInt = BN_new();`. You might also consider checking the return value from [`BN_mul_word`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/BN_mul_word.html): *"... there is no limit on the size of the numbers manipulated by these functions, but return values must always be checked in case a memory allocation error has occurred"*.

Comment: I changed the code to use the 'new' function, but 'init' should be sufficient for stack variables. Output is identical. I also added a check on the 'mul' function, but it returns no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem is not in OpenSSL but in my output window, unexpectedly truncating the string without a marker or something.